# Is there a way to run a command inside a devspace as a one-liner without entering the devspace?

Tags: devspace

I'm using a development environment that is set up via [devspace](https://www.devspace.sh/). Usually, I enter a devspace using `devspace enter` before I execute any commands.

I want to `cat` out the contents of a file -- let's say `myFile.txt` -- in the home folder of the devspace *without* using `devspace enter`. Is there a way I can do that using a one-liner?

Comment: Did you tried something like `devspace enter cat ~/myFile.txt` or `devspace enter 'cat ~/myFile.txt'` from the docs looks like it may work

Comment: Yup. I was just missing the `--container` flag. So the winning combination was  `devspace enter --container myPod cat myFile.txt`. (Technically, this leaves the user in the devspace, but that's fine for my purposes.) Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are welcome, I just read docs :) missing part in the question is within a pod you have more then one container, so you want to select one without interaction